# how to persist filter in ag-grid vuejs

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

How to persist the filter in ag-grid vuejs . I'm trying to apply filter but when I click on a row for looking the data inside the row node the filter selection is removed I meant the grid load from the starting (reset filter). how to persist this filter.
**second problem** and I'm facing one more problem is that the selection of row is not working in a long time ... I have applied checkbox in the header but when I select the checkbox after a couple of seconds it will automatically deselect ..so my second question is how to apply checkbox the will not deselect automatically. one particular node check box is not working also

thanks in advance I'm new in this technology please help me out from core ...

Comment: Please create a reproducible example using StackBlitz (see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-vue-hello-world)).

Answer (score 1):

I guess for the first problem of yours you should set `newRowsAction` to `'keep'` like this.

```
{field: 'year', filter: 'number', filterParams: {newRowsAction: 'keep'}}
```

This property is for when using the Client Side Row Model only. When set to 'clear', updating the data in the grid by calling `api.setRowData()` (or updating the rowData property if bound by a framework) will clear (reset) the filter. If you instead set this to 'keep', the grid will keep its currently set filter when the data is updated.

Default: 'clear'

for the second problem of your its really hard to interpret based on words so it will be good if you can create minimum code working demo(reproducing the error) on plunkr or stackblitz so that we can help you.